# How to get a last modified file date of a subfolder inside a document library

Tags: sharepoint

When I upload a file in to a subfolder the subfolder modified date is not updated where as the document library last modified date is updated

Now I want to find which file is last updated inside a subfolder using csom

Answer (score 0):

You could use caml query to get the lasted modified item in a library like this:

```
$list = $Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = '<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>'
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$Context.load(items)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: i have to find last updated file date for a specific sub folder